# Java OffsetDateTime isAfter and isBefore handle timezone?

Tags: java, java-8

Does `OffsetDateTime` `isAfter` and `isBefore` method handle timezones when doing comparison?

So if one `OffsetDateTime` is in PST and the other one is UTC, will it automatically do the timezone conversion and compare correctly?

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` cannot handle PST, it can only handle things like UTC-8, which is rather different from PST. You can use `ZonedDateTime` if you want PST.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is straightforward to test!

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final OffsetDateTime odtMinusSeven = OffsetDateTime.of(2016, 01, 01, 8, 30, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));
        final OffsetDateTime odtMinusSix   = OffsetDateTime.of(2016, 01, 01, 8, 30, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(-6));

        System.out.println(odtMinusSeven.isAfter(odtMinusSix));
        // true
    }
}
```